# отключение слайдера для мобильной версии в slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, slider

Кто обладает информацией, подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить `слайдер` для мобильной версии в *slider revolution*, думаю через код. Так как в админ панели отключаешь, но ничего не меняется, отображается как и прежде

Comment: Вы можете отключить его через меню general четвертый пункт:
https://www.themepunch.com/slider-revolution/module-general-settings/

Comment: https://c.radikal.ru/c41/1912/29/c3f60ceed5b6.png             нет таких пунктов

Comment: https://d.radikal.ru/d23/1912/32/67a01df190cc.png  в админ панели не работает

Comment: Вы вниз прокрутите и будет этот пункт.

Comment: не работает, как отображалось на мобильных так и осталось. Кэш чистила не помогает

Comment: Он проверяет с какого устройства вы заходите, если вы просто сужаете окно браузера - то это не затригирит отключение. Если хотите проверять с пк,то переключитесь на моб режим.

Comment: я с пк переключала на мобильный и с мобильного тоже заходила и кэш чистила при этом, не работает. Возможно дело в том, что на странице несколько слайдеров.  https://qarchive.ru/2265541_znachok_izmenenija_slai_dera_revolution_na_mobil_nom_ustroi_stve

Comment: Сработало, не знаю почему но вчера не показывало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где то на странице, на которой расположен пропишите стиль:

```
<style>@media (max-width:450px) {.slider_wrap {display:none;}}</style>
```

Либо подключите запись отдельно через стили.

Если прописать это правило через "Настроить" -> "Дополнительные стили", то правило не сработает, ибо там не поддерживаются media запросы.